# Using SoapUI with Axis2 and Rampart to test Secure Web Service

Tags: apache-axis, soapui, rampart

I am using Axis2 and Rampart to develop a secure web service and deploy it on jBoss. After successfully deploying the service on jBoss, I and using SoapUI to test the service. I get following error:

wsse:InvalidSecurity
         Expected transport is "https" but incoming transport found : "http"

How do I configure HTTPS transport using SoapUI?

Answer (score 0):

Does your endpoint have http or https?

[From rampart sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/rampart/branches/1_5/modules/rampart-samples/policy/sample01/README.txt)

> Rampart enforces the use of HTTPS transport and that 
>   {http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy}RampartConfig assertion provides
>   additional information required to secure the message.
>
> Expected result :
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Expected transport is "https" but incoming transport found : "http"
>
> This sample uses http transport while the policy enforces https transport. Thus you
>   get a error message as mentioned above. You can find a complete tutorial on transport level
>   security here. http://wso2.org/library/3190

Your web service is probably using http when it should be using https.

Comment: In 2022 link to article is broken but copy available through web archive https://web.archive.org/web/20130529203537/http://wso2.org/library/3190